Can anyone explain the following composition of the relation?
Can anyone explain the following composition of the relation?
Let $R$ be the relation on the set of all students defined by $αRβ$ iff student $α$ and student $β$ are in at least one common class and $α ≠β$. I have to decide the correctness of these two statements. I am not able to make proper English statement for these to proceed.
True/False:

If $(α,β)\in R^2$  then $α$ and $β$ are in at least two common classes.
If $(α,β)\in R^2$  then there exists $γ$ such that $α$  and $γ$ are in at least one common class and $β$  and $γ$  are in at least one common class.


Main idea:
By definition, $(a,b) \in \color{red}{R^2}$, if $\exists \, m \in S$ (where $S$ is the set of all students) such that $(a,m) \in R$ and $(m,b) \in R$. In the context of your problem, it means if $a$ is related to $b$ via $\color{red}{R^2}$, then there exists a student $m$ such that $a$ is related to $m$ (which means $a$ and $m$ have at least one common class). Likewise, $m$ and $b$ must have at least one common class (NOTE: the class(es) that $a$ and $m$ share need not be the same classes that $m$ and $b$ share).
Imagine, student $a$ has courses $\{c_1,c_2\}$, student $b$ has courses $\{d_1,d_2,d_3\}$ and a student $m$ has courses $\{c_2,d_1, d_2, e_3\}$.
Based on my description above: can we say $(a,b) \in \color{red}{R^2}$?
Hope you can take it from here.

second statement is just the definition of the composition of relations. So based on your example $a$ and $m$ share $c_2$ subject common; $b$ and $m$ share $d_1,d_2$ subjects , so $(a,b) \in R^2$. Correct?????

@Priya Yes, $(a,b) \in R^2$. Now this example can help you answer both your questions.
